# .htaccess - Rewriting requests for specific website to a subdirectory causing 500 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my entire .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On

       # Rewrite all requests for site1 to the "site1" subdirectory
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1.com [NC]
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site1/$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

So I am trying to forward all requests to a subdirectory called "site1". The above gives me a 500 error.

My directory:

```
-public_html
    .htaccess
    -site1
    -site2
```

e.g. The request `site1.com/home.html` should be served the file at `site1/home.html`

I can't just change the file `site1` to `site1.com` since I will later be hosting another website on the same server and so I will be adding another subdirectory called `site2` which will be used to serve the `site2.com` content.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On

       # Rewrite all requests for site1 to the "site1" subdirectory
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site1
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site1/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

You need to exclude your "site1" folder from rewrite, so that it doesnt rewrite to itself.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much.